# Removing word and replacing character in a column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to change values in the column `DSFS` of a I've dataframe imported.

```
MemberID,Year,DSFS,DrugCount
48925661,Y2,9-10 months,7+
90764620,Y3,8- 9 months,3
61221204,Y1,2- 3 months,1
```

For example, "9-10 months" needs to be changed to 9_10.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [175]: df.replace({'DSFS': {r'(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)': r'\1_\2'}}, regex=True)
Out[175]:
   MemberID Year         DSFS DrugCount
0  48925661   Y2  9_10 months        7+
1  90764620   Y3   8_9 months         3
2  61221204   Y1   2_3 months         1
```

In place:

```
In [176]: df
Out[176]:
   MemberID Year         DSFS DrugCount
0  48925661   Y2  9-10 months        7+
1  90764620   Y3  8- 9 months         3
2  61221204   Y1  2- 3 months         1

In [177]: df.replace({'DSFS': {r'(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+)': r'\1_\2'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)

In [178]: df
Out[178]:
   MemberID Year         DSFS DrugCount
0  48925661   Y2  9_10 months        7+
1  90764620   Y3   8_9 months         3
2  61221204   Y1   2_3 months         1
```

If you want to preserve only numbers you can do it this way:

```
In [183]: df.replace({'DSFS': {r'(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+).*': r'\1_\2'}}, regex=True)
Out[183]:
   MemberID Year  DSFS DrugCount
0  48925661   Y2  9_10        7+
1  90764620   Y3   8_9         3
2  61221204   Y1   2_3         1
```

Comment: This helped thanks! Here's my issue, I need to place **df.replace({'DSFS': {r'(\d+)\s*\-\s*(\d+).*': r'\1_\2'}}, regex=True)** in a helper function, i.e. one in which I only have the code for a conversion, not opening a dataframe. How would I code this replace step in a function?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have pandas installed, but the solution should be working for `df` objects.

```
string="48925661,Y2,9-10 months,7+"
"_".join(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string.split(",")[2]))
```

Test result:

```
>>> "_".join(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', string.split(",")[2]))
'9_10'
```

python script:

```
$ cat test.py
with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    next(inputs)  # skip the first line
    for line in inputs:
        parts = line.strip().split(",")
        parts[2] = "_".join(re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', parts[2]))
        print(",".join(parts))
```

Result:

```
$python test.py                                
48925661,Y2,9_10,7+
90764620,Y3,8_9,3
61221204,Y1,2_3,1
```

Comment: \b is word boundary and \d+ is numeric number, it is matching all numeric values in a given string

Answer (score 0):

If you could use an iterator that will be better. But these are comma separated values. Just use `split()` in a nifty way. Like the following

```
cleaned = [line.split(",")[2].replace("-", "_") for line in source]
```

where `source` if a file object, a big list of strings or an iterator emitting strings(the best one)